# GetHashCode returns different Values

Tags: c#, linq, hashcode

I'm using Linq-to-Sql to query a SQL Server database. This query returns a List of an entity in my database. My underlying data is NOT changing.

Once I have received the List, I call GetHashCode on it in order to test for equality. Oddly, the hash value is always different. Why would it always be different?

Thank you,

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you override `GetHashCode` to be based on the contents, as the answers state, you'll still need to deal with collisions, which are objects that have different values but resolve to the same hash code.  You won't be able to have a collision-free hash with that type of data (ever), you can only reduce the collision rate.  You need to use `Equals` to ensure objects with the same hash are really the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are different beacuse they are different object references.

You need to override [Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) for your object, based on the object data, if you want to behave in that way.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.90%29.aspx) you have an example about how to do it, and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) a blog post about the guidelines overriding the `GetHashCode()` method. Hope it helps.

```
class TwoDPoint : System.Object
{
    public readonly int x, y;

    public TwoDPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
        if (p == null) return false;

        // Return true if the fields match
        return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return x ^ y;
    }
}
```

As [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) said in his comment, keep in mind that even overriding `GetHashCode()` method, you won't be able to have a collision-free hash with that type of data (ever), you can only reduce the collision rate. You need to use `Equals()` to ensure objects with the same hash are really the same

Answer (score 2):

Did you override `GetHashCode()`?  If not the default implementation is to give you a hash code based on the *reference* of the list.  It will not have anything to do with the *contents* of the list.

So two different instances means two different hash codes.

To check for list equality override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode()`) on your entity class and use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) on the list.